# Getting blank response when making json post request using wininet Api in vc++ code

Tags: json, visual-c++, post, wininet

I am making a json post request using wininet Api in vc++, but I am receiving blank response.I have checked my request header and request body in fiddler and its working fine there.Following are my HttpOpenRequest and HttpSendRequest

```
m_hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(m_hConnect, 
                _T("POST"),
                szURI,
                NULL,
                lpszReferrer,
                NULL,
                INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION 
                | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE | INTERNET_FLAG_FORMS_SUBMIT 
                | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS 
                | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP,
                (DWORD) &m_context); 

TCHAR* szHeaders =  _T("Content-Type:application/json\r\n");
TCHAR* szPostData = _T("{\"command\":\"remotecontrol\",\"method\":\"countmon.getgatestatus\",\"param\":\"2\"}");

HttpSendRequest(m_hRequest, 
                 szHeaders, 
                 _tcslen(szHeaders),  
                szPostData,
                 _tcslen(szPostData)))
```

I badly need somebody help on this.Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the response on changing character type from unicode to multibyte character in application properties..I dont know why ,but i thinks its not working on sending json string as unicode